# How come I get NA values when joining non-spatial object to geometry data/polygon?

Tags: r, join, geometry, na, shapefile

I am trying to join a non-spatial object (Merged_Census2011) to a shapefile polygon (LDN_wards) by "ward.name". It seems to work fine until I look at the newly created object and see that all data has turn into NAs. Here's how I proceeded.

```
#Join Merged_Census2011 data to LDN_wards shapefile
LDN_wards <- readOGR(dsn = "data", layer = "LDN_wards")
head(LDN_wards@data)
#Explore the object
plot(LDN_wards)
summary(LDN_wards)
names(Merged_Census2011)
names(LDN_wards)
names(LDN_wards) <- c("Code", "ward.name") #rename LND-wards name heading to ward.name so it can be matched later  

#Join datasets
LDN_wards@data <- left_join(LDN_wards@data, Merged_Census2011)
head(LDN_wards@data)
```

And I get:

```
LDN_wards@data <- left_join(LDN_wards@data, Merged_Census2011)
Joining by: "ward.name"
Warning message:
In left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
> head(LDN_wards@data)
   Code    ward.name ward.code.x electorate votescast ward.code.y per.owner per.white per.noquals per.degree per.couple
1 E05000001   Aldersgate        <NA>         NA        NA        <NA>        NA        NA          NA         NA         NA
2 E05000002      Aldgate        <NA>         NA        NA        <NA>        NA        NA          NA         NA
```

I have the intuition this is because there is a different number of row between the two sets. Could that be the issue? Is it not possible to join datasets with different row levels (whereby the missing data in one just remains unmatched by the corresponding observations)?
I had compared the two datasets  as follows:

```
#Compare the two datasets
nrow(LDN_wards)
nrow(Merged_Census2011)
LDN_wards$ward.name %in% Merged_Census2011$ward.name
LDN_wards$ward.name %in% Merged_Census2011$ward.name
> nrow(LDN_wards)
[1] 787
> nrow(Merged_Census2011)
[1] 668
> LDN_wards$ward.name %in% Merged_Census2011$ward.name
  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSEFALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [21] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  [41]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE ETC...
> summary(LDN_wards$ward.name %in% Merged_Census2011$ward.name) 
   Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
logical      24     763       0
```

Could it be because of the FALSE=24? If it is, how do I delete those FALSE?

Apologies if this sounds obvious, I'm fairly new :)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try LDN_wards@data[complete.cases(LDN_wards@data),]
My intuition is telling me that the first 24 lines of your LDN_wards@data are not matched, so when you do a head you only get NA results.

Comment: Indeed, I just checked and the rest of the data is here. Many thanks for spotting this to me Ken Yeoh :)

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried again using the (newly discovered) inner_join function and it seemed to work. If I understood well, the inner_join function only merges the matching rows... So I thought it would be better. And indeed, I do not get NA values anymore. But strangely I get duplicated observations... So if anyone has a better suggestion, you're very welcome to share. See my proceedings below.

```
#Join datasets
LDN_wards@data <- inner_join(LDN_wards@data, Merged_Census2011)
head(LDN_wards@data, n=10)

> #Join datasets
> LDN_wards@data <- inner_join(LDN_wards@data, Merged_Census2011)
Joining by: c("ward.name", "ward.code.x", "electorate", "votescast","ward.code.y", "per.owner", "per.white", "per.noquals", "per.degree", "per.couple", "per.higher.managerial", "per.christian", "per.no.car", "per.limill", "per.goodhealth", "per.males", "per.aged60plus")
Warning message:
In inner_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
joining character vector and factor, coercing into character vector
> head(LDN_wards@data, n=10)
    Code      ward.name ward.code.x electorate votescast ward.code.y per.owner per.white per.noquals per.degree per.couple
1  E05000007         Bridge   E05000497       8677      5654   E05000497      69.8      71.9        19.9       29.9       55.3
2  E05000026          Abbey   E05000026       8110      4712   E05000026      32.7      28.1        16.4       34.5       47.2
3  E05000026          Abbey   E05000026       8110      4712   E05000455      48.5      73.4        10.1       55.4       52.4
4  E05000026          Abbey   E05000455       7250      4808   E05000026      32.7      28.1        16.4       34.5       47.2
5  E05000026          Abbey   E05000455       7250      4808   E05000455      48.5      73.4        10.1       55.4       52.4
6  E05000027         Alibon   E05000027       6971      4127   E05000027      45.1      70.1        31.2       16.7       49.2
7  E05000028      Becontree   E05000028       7535      4538   E05000028      46.7      58.8        28.0       20.6
```